# How to avoid stack overflow Error in Get_It Package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection

To avoid this kind of error in Flutter get Package:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Builder:
Stack Overflow

Avoid calling depending widget or class from a depending widget or class

if you have :

````
class A{
var x=locator<B>;
}```

Avoid doing this in class B
```class B{
var x=locator<A>;
}```


:) its crazy but possible...have fun
````

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a variable, make it a getter:

```dart
class A{
  B get x => locator<B>()
}

class B{
  A get x => locator<A>();
}
```